# How to use outer query column in inner query condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to use subquery in a select statement but I want to pass the column data to subquery so that it could filter data for that row which is being processed. How do we do this or is this even possible ?

```
select 
[SRP Code], [Master Code],  [Product Desc], [Pack Desc],[Information],  [Store],

case when ([SRP Code] <> [Master Code])
then
    isnull([38],0) + (select (e.stock/er.unit) as 'Stock' from erp_stock e join  
    erpcustomerlinking er on e.productcode = er.mastercode where 

    er.mastercode = [Master Code] <-- here I want the column

    and weekno = 38     group by e.stock,er.unit)
else
    isnull([38],0)
end as [38],[36],[37],[35],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50]

from [dbo].[F91FE39A-F618-40A8-A6F7-C721A379EE76]

where [SRP Code] = 401794
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
Create table test(id int, name varchar(20), age int);
create table salary(id int, salary int, testid int);

insert into test values(1,'jitu',12);
insert into test values(2,'kapil',12);                 
insert into test values(3,'ajay',12);
insert into test values(4,'vijay',12);

insert into salary values(1, 200, 1);
insert into salary values(2, 300, 2);
insert into salary values(3, 400, 3);
insert into salary values(4, 500, 4);

select *, (select salary from salary where test.id=testid) as Salary from test
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/717e9/3/0